# Remove Metabox on Wordpress pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to remove the metabox on pages with certain slugs. Is this possible?

I have seen the remove_meta_box() function but cannot seem to get it to work.

This is the box I am trying to remove:

[image]

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a meta_box you want to remove, it's the 'editor,' which is a feature of posts. You'll want to use `remove_post_type_support()`

Try:

```
add_action( 'admin_head', 'custom_remove_editor' );

function custom_remove_editor() {
  global $post;
  $post_id = $post->ID

  if( $post_id == 1 || $post_id == 2 || $post_id == 3 ) {
   remove_post_type_support( 'post', 'editor' );
  }
}
```

Of course, the numbers in the `if()` statement should match the post_ids you want this to be removed on.

Comment: Thank You! I actually had to modify the code to this:

add_action( 'admin_head', 'custom_remove_editor' );

function custom_remove_editor() {
    global $post;
    $post_id = $post->ID;

  if( $post_id == 206 || $post_id == 232 || $post_id == 218 ) {
      remove_post_type_support( 'page', 'editor' );
  }
}

Comment: Yes, that's great. That's exactly what you should have done. I updated the final sentence to add clarity to that change.